# Error processing "launch": The ionic live reload server exited unexpectedly

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to launch an Ionic app on my Android device from VS Code, using the [vscode-cordova extension](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cordova).

My `launch.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Run android on device",
            "type": "cordova",
            "request": "launch",
            "platform": "android",
            "target": "device",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "ionicLiveReload": true
        }
    ]
}
```

But I get following error message:

> [cordova-tools] Error processing "launch": The Ionic live reload server exited
>   unexpectedly

The debug console does offer a bit more information:

> Launching for android (This may take a while)...
>
> Starting Ionic dev server (live reload: true)
>
> The Ionic live reload server exited unexpectedly

How can I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to run `ionic cordova run android -l` revealed the issue:

> [ERROR] Multiple network interfaces detected!
>
> You must select an external-facing IP for the dev server that your device or emulator has access to with the --address option.

So adding the `--address` option to the `runArguments` of my launch.json as lined out in the [readme](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cordova#choose-the-cordova-debug-environment) resolved my issue:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Run android on device",
            "type": "cordova",
            "request": "launch",
            "platform": "android",
            "target": "device",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "ionicLiveReload": true,
            "runArguments": [
                "--address 192.168.1.2"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Where 192.168.1.2 is the ip address of my dev laptop. Also make sure this ip address is reachable from your device.